# Android fragment onCreateView() never called

Tags: java, android, android-activity, null, fragment

I've been searching for a while now, but I can't seem to find an answer to the following question:
Why does `onCreateView` never get triggered? This code is the code generated by Android Studio when creating a new `MainActivity` plus some of the code I wrote.

I want to use `setTextConfig(...,...,...)` to set the text in the text fields. But I can't seem to get them using `findviewbyid(R.id....);` because `v` is always null, even `getView();` returns null.

```
 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private View v;
    private EditText etCustomerName, etDeviceID;
    private Spinner select;
    public PlaceholderFragment() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        return v;
    }

    public void setTextConfig(String customerName, String selectedOption, int deviceID){
        View vv = getView();
        //init form controls
        etCustomerName = (EditText)vv.findViewById(R.id.etCustomerName);
        etDeviceID = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.etDeviceId);
        select = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.select);


        etCustomerName.setText(customerName);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter)select.getAdapter();
        int index = adapter.getPosition(selectedOption);
        select.setSelection(index);

        etDeviceID = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.etDeviceId);
        etDeviceID.setText(Integer.toString(deviceID), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    }
}
```

If you need more detailed info, just ask :)

Comment: are you adding this `Fragment` to `Activity`?

Comment: @Gopal Rao 

I am using this code to add the fragment.
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

Comment: FYI- if `Fragment` is added to the `Activity` properly, then `onCreateView()` will be called for sure...

Comment: @Gopal Rao If i don't want to set the text, the app show the fragment as it is supposed to. I just can't set the text inside of the EditText items. 

I tried using setContentView(R.id.fragment_main), then i could set the text (it didn't give any errors) but the text wasn't visible in the fragment.

Comment: when you are calling `setTextConfig()` method? make sure that you are calling this method after `Fragment` is attached to the `Activity` otherwise `getView()` method returns `null`...

Comment: I do that in a function that is called at the end of the onCreate

Comment: maintain the reference to the `Fragment` and try it `onWindowFocusChanged()` method of `Activity`.

Comment: That did the trick. Why does it take that long to have the event triggered?

Comment: And, as i moved on, it's even better to use the onActivityCreated method in the fragment class.